# How to change the sort order of the customer address attributes?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, customer-address-attribute

As title. Here is the current sorting of customer address attributes using the following SQL statement:

```
select ea.attribute_code, eaa.sort_order 
from eav_entity_attribute as eaa 
left join eav_attribute as ea on ea.attribute_id = eaa.attribute_id 
where eaa.entity_type_id=2 
and attribute_code is not null 
order by sort_order;
```

And the result is:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| attribute_code      | sort_order |
+---------------------+------------+
| prefix              |         10 |
| firstname           |         20 |
| middlename          |         30 |
| lastname            |         40 |
| suffix              |         50 |
| company             |         60 |
| flat                |         62 |
| floor               |         64 |
| block               |         66 |
| building            |         68 |
| street              |         70 |
| country_id          |         80 |
| region_id           |         90 |
| region              |         90 |
| city                |        100 |
| postcode            |        110 |
| telephone           |        120 |
| fax                 |        130 |
| vat_is_valid        |        132 |
| vat_request_id      |        133 |
| vat_request_date    |        134 |
| vat_request_success |        135 |
| vat_id              |        140 |
+---------------------+------------+
```

Let's say I want to change `city` to have a `sort_order` of 69 instead of 100, how can I do it? I know writing SQL can do it but I want to do it on code level.

Comment: OK I found an answer on `vendor\magento\module-customer\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateCustomerAddressAttributesSortOrder.php`

Answer (score 0):

Glad you find it, but I would have said that going to `EavAttributeRepository` to get the `city` attribute and simply setting the new value before saving would have done the trick. This seems to the general way yo do it no matter what your attribute is.
Considering your way, take care that you are not supposed to modify vendor files.

Comment: Of course I won't modify it, just create a new setup file based on it.